# Find and Delete element from an array by first letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a dynamic array. Value comes from function by method push, I want to be able to check if an array already has element "X" with same letters, so I want to remove this element and then push new element. How can I do that? 
This is **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a5EoKcN249rznFKOZUvn?p=preview)** with my code

code

```
    $scope.selectedCat = [];
        $scope.selectedCl = [];

        $scope.updateCategory = function (categoryId) {

            if ($scope.selectedCat.indexOf(categoryId) > -1) {
                $scope.selectedCat.splice($scope.selectedCat.indexOf(categoryId), 1);
            } else {
                $scope.selectedCat.push(categoryId);
            }

           $scope.queryCategory = 'categoryId=in=(' + $scope.selectedCat + ")"
          // console.log($scope.queryCategory)
            //Optional, to reload on change.
          $scope.requestSelected ($scope.queryCategory)

        };

        $scope.updateClass = function (classId) {

            if ($scope.selectedCl.indexOf(classId) > -1) {
                $scope.selectedCl.splice($scope.selectedCl.indexOf(classId), 1);
            } else {
                $scope.selectedCl.push(classId);
            }

             $scope.queryClass = 'eventClassId=in=(' + $scope.selectedCl + ")"
            // console.log($scope.queryClass)
            //Optional, to reload on change.
            $scope.requestSelected ($scope.queryClass)

        };


        $scope.filter = []
        var string;
        $scope.requestSelected = function (param){

       if($scope.filter already has an elem with the same letters as param){

         // delete this elem then 

         $scope.filter.push(param)
      } else {

         $scope.filter.push(param)

    }

          // final result 
          string = $scope.filter.join(";")

          console.log(string)

        }
```

**UPDATED**
With help @Anton, I finally finished logic for creating a right request. This is working [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WcMWg2MBSojqxPkd2p5g?p=preview). Maybe it will be useful for somebody

Comment: Do you want to check if two elements are exact matches or if one element is contained within the other? Please clarify.

Comment: It would generally be useful to simplify any problem into the most important parts. It seems like there's a lot going on in your code, but not all of it is necessary for us to understand the problem. If you could write some new code that just has the essentials it would make it much easier to debug things and for others to understand the issues involved.

Comment: @NeilA. Exactly in example I want to check if $scope.filter already has an element 'categoryId' or ''eventClassId" matches with param, and remove it, then add new param to $scope.filter array

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I'm sorry but I already removed a lot of unnecessary code from example and left only essentials things. I wanted to show whole process, how I'm getting the last variable string, and I believe this is really important to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always add a condition here `$scope.filter.push(param)`, instead of that you have to separate different fields for each search field and do something like this:

```
           var filterOptions = {
               filterBy: '&$filter=',
               filterParam: "",
               classId: '',
               categoryId: ''
           };

           $scope.selectedCat = [];
           $scope.selectedCl = [];

           $scope.updateCategory = function (categoryId) {

               if ($scope.selectedCat.indexOf(categoryId) > -1) {
                   $scope.selectedCat.splice($scope.selectedCat.indexOf(categoryId), 1);
               } else {
                   $scope.selectedCat.push(categoryId);
               }

             filterOptions.categoryId = 'categoryId=in=(' + $scope.selectedCat + ")"

             filterOptions.filterParam = filterOptions.classId + ";" + filterOptions.categoryId
           console.log(filterOptions.filterParam)
           };

           $scope.updateClass = function (classId) {

               if ($scope.selectedCl.indexOf(classId) > -1) {
                   $scope.selectedCl.splice($scope.selectedCl.indexOf(classId), 1);
               } else {
                   $scope.selectedCl.push(classId);
               }

               filterOptions.classId = 'eventClassId=in=(' + $scope.selectedCl + ")"

               filterOptions.filterParam = filterOptions.classId + ";" + filterOptions.categoryId
               console.log(filterOptions.filterParam)

           };
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it was helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 //Create new Array and put element on it..
 $scope.filter = []
 $scope.TempArr = [];
 var string;
$scope.requestSelected = function(param) {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filter.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.filter[i] == param) {
    $scope.TempArr.push(param);
  } else {
    $scope.TempArr.push(param);
  }
  if (i == $scope.filter.length - 1) {
    //$scope.filter=[]; if you want then you can update new element only
    $scope.filter = $scope.TempArr;
    string = $scope.filter.join(";")

    console.log(string)
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I have put your code to my plunker, console log is always empty. This is forked plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/nAoFPcY34NdRrBUW0WFL?p=preview

Comment: I'm really sorry but `console.log($scope.filter)` shows me only an empty array

Comment: check  $scope.requestSelected = function(param) {console.log(param);}..Its always going into else.Check param value at the top so you will get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you could do this (names and function calls simplified):

```
var filter = ["abc", "123"], param = "_?!"

var found = filter.indexOf(param);
if (found !== -1) {
  // filter already has an elem with the same letters as param
  filter.splice(found, 1);
}

filter.push(param);
```

Are there any nuances I've missed?